MySQL Server Shutting Down Unexpectedly on XAMPP
I'm encountering an issue where my MySQL server on XAMPP shuts down unexpectedly. The error message in the XAMPP control panel states Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
So far, I've tried:

Restarting MySQL multiple times.
Reviewing the error log, but I’m not sure how to interpret the warnings.
Changing the port numbers in my.ini, but this hasn't resolved the issue.

Any help on how to fix this would be greatly appreciated!


this is not a programming question, but a database admin one, so it is off topic here on SO. 2) even if you find a q/a site where this question would be on topic, nobody can answer it without any specific error message.


I have faced this problem before and it was because of i had installed mysql itself seperately from xampp before. maybe it is the same thing for you. maybe a mysql server is running in a background in your system.
if your using windows go to your Services.msc. for that press windows+R, type Services.msc then try to find mysql and then righ-click on it and then stop.
i hope it works.

I encountered this error to, and found a solution that worked for me, though i don't know why it works nor what the cause of the error is. I got this error and then reinstalled XAMPP, used my server for a few hours and the next time I started it up, had the error again. After searching around I found the following:

Go to "xampp root on your computer/Mysql/Data/"
Rename any and all files starting with 'ib_logfile'. Rename, instead of delete so if you need or want to you can replace them.

I found the solution on this site
